# Laravel using route helper within a service

Tags: php, laravel, soa

I'm using the Laravel framework and creating a service.

Should I use the route helper function inside a service? Or even the Laravel Route facade.

```php
...
class SomecController extends Controller 
{
 private SomeService $service;
 public function __construct(SomeService $service) { $this->service = $service; }
 public function __invoke() {
  return $this->service->run();
 }
}

class SomeService {
 public function run() {
  return [
   'actionRoute' => route('some.route'),
   'currentRoute' => Route::currentRouteName(),
  ];
 }
}
```

Comment: what ever you prefer

Comment: Does something not work?

Comment: No it would work - just should I not try to decouple the Laravel route stuffs from the service

Comment: IE, instead of passing in the Illiminate\Support\Request object to the service, it would be better to pass in just a array or class that holds the specific properties from the request. 

I was thinking would that also apply to route names

Comment: I don't want to use the Route facade. But i also don't want to inject the router. Since then the service is coupled to laravel

Comment: Is that thinking correct?